# Unable to Debug a Windows Service in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

We are migrating a Visual Studio 2010 solution to Visual Studio 2012.  As usual Murphy's Law is rearing it's ugly head.

What I am trying to do is relatively simple and I have done it many times in the past - I just want to Attach to a running windows service process and step into it's code.

FWIW with the other projects of this solution I am able to step into and debug the code as expected - it's just this Windows Service that is giving us problems.

We have already verfiied the obvious things that can cause this to fail...

1: We HAVE already ensured that the .pdb debug symbols are included alongside the service executable and DLL's

2: We ARE running a debug build of the service.

I am assuming that this is just a stupid setting in Visual Studio 2012 someplace that is causing this...  Either that or I am missing something simple and just need a second pair of eyes...

Comment: have you tried Debugger.Launch() inside your windows service and then install and start. As it will hit the line it will launch the debugger for you.

Comment: are you getting an error? can't set breakpoints? can't attach?

Comment: Are you running the service locally, or on another machine?

Answer (score 1):

The absolute easiest way to debug a service is to insert an `Assert(0)` in your debug build somewhere in the beginning of the Running() code. The assert will pop up while the service is running, allowing you to then attach the debugger of your choice to it. Then you can do whatever you want (such as set break points, change values in memory, etc).

If Visual Studio 2012 still won't attach to your asserting service, then something is seriously off in the installation or configuration. If it attachs but won't let you see anything, you probably need to enable "native code" debugging when you are attaching.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1. Building the windows service in debug mode;
2. Publish it and install it on your development machine;
3. Start the service from the Services management console;
4. Attach to process from within Visual Studio 2012

After this my breakpoint got hit immediately.

Please note: at step 4 you may need to select "Show processes from all users" to make your service visible to be able to attach to it because it is likely to run under the SYSTEM account.

Hope this helps you out Chase.